# Python: DataReader wont fetch data from yahoo finance

Tags: python

guys!

Tried to get historical data using yahoo API, despite following formula, changing dates, stocks, checking packages etc with no success. Chat gpt cannot find errors. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!
[Screen shot of code and error message:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmLNM.png)

Comment: Please share the code as text next time so people could have an easier time working on the issue.

Comment: Thanks for critique Bill, I will make sure to follow your suggestion in future question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a library bug (see Appendix). Try the following [workaround](https://www.nbshare.io/notebook/63624410/Pandas-Datareader-To-Download-Stocks-Data-From-Google-And-Yahoo-Finance/) using `yfinance` package.

### Code

Requirement: `pip install yfinance`

```
from datetime import datetime
import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override()
from pandas_datareader import data as web

# remove the 'yahoo' parameter
goog = web.DataReader('GOOG', start=datetime(2020,1,1), end=datetime(2021,2,24))
```

### Result

```
In [4]: goog
Out[4]: 
                Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close    Volume
Date                                                                            
2020-01-02   67.077499   68.406998   67.077499   68.368500   68.368500  28132000
2020-01-03   67.392998   68.625000   67.277199   68.032997   68.032997  23728000
2020-01-06   67.500000   69.824997   67.500000   69.710503   69.710503  34646000
2020-01-07   69.897003   70.149498   69.518997   69.667000   69.667000  30054000
2020-01-08   69.603996   70.579002   69.542000   70.216003   70.216003  30560000
...                ...         ...         ...         ...         ...       ...
2021-02-17  105.000000  106.682999  104.945999  106.415497  106.415497  21418000
2021-02-18  105.519501  106.636749  105.185501  105.860001  105.860001  22432000
2021-02-19  105.963501  106.526497  104.870499  105.056999  105.056999  29148000
2021-02-22  103.349998  104.570999  103.107002  103.244003  103.244003  27350000
2021-02-23  101.250504  104.100502  100.100998  103.542999  103.542999  33348000

[288 rows x 6 columns]
```

### Appendix

I am able to reproduce the same reported error by invoking the internal `YahooDailyReader` class.

```
from datetime import datetime
from pandas_datareader.yahoo.daily import YahooDailyReader

goog = YahooDailyReader(symbols='GOOG', start=datetime(2020,1,1), end=datetime(2021,2,24))
```

**Error**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 1
----> 1 goog = YahooDailyReader(symbols='GOOG', start=datetime(2020,1,1), end=datetime(2021,2,24)).read()

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/default/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py:253, in _DailyBaseReader.read(self)
    251 # If a single symbol, (e.g., 'GOOG')
    252 if isinstance(self.symbols, (string_types, int)):
--> 253     df = self._read_one_data(self.url, params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
    254 # Or multiple symbols, (e.g., ['GOOG', 'AAPL', 'MSFT'])
    255 elif isinstance(self.symbols, DataFrame):

File /opt/anaconda3/envs/default/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas_datareader/yahoo/daily.py:153, in YahooDailyReader._read_one_data(self, url, params)
    151 try:
    152     j = json.loads(re.search(ptrn, resp.text, re.DOTALL).group(1))
--> 153     data = j["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["HistoricalPriceStore"]
    154 except KeyError:
    155     msg = "No data fetched for symbol {} using {}"

TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'
```